# Google sign in redirect back to login page if email not in the database

Tags: php, html, google-api

i am kinda new to PHP and not sure if this has been answered before i cant really find anything. what im asking for help with is with a google sign in if the email address is not in the database i would like it to redirect the user back to the login page, i have attached the code for the login below if anyone can help it will be highly appreciated thank you.

````
//session_start();

//index.php
include('classDev.php');

//Include Configuration File
include('config.php');

$login_button = '';


if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{

 $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);


 if(!isset($token['error']))
 {
 
  $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

 
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];


  $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);

 
  $gData = $google_service->userinfo->get();

 
  if(!empty($gData['given_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $gData['given_name'];
  }

  if(!empty($gData['family_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $gData['family_name'];
  }

  //if (empty(($data->select_where("user",$where_condition)))) {
  //  header("location: index.php?status=failure");
  //}

  if(!empty($gData['email']))
  {
    $where_condition = array("email" => $gData['email']);
    if (($data->select_where("user",$where_condition))) {
     $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $gData['email'];
  }
}
if (empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
    
  //echo "please enter an email address that is valid.";

    //header('location: index.php?status=failure');
  }


  if(!empty($gData['gender']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_gender'] = $gData['gender'];
  }

  if(!empty($gData['picture']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_image'] = $gData['picture'];
  }
 }
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{

 $login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'">Login With Google</a>';
}

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHP Login using Google Account</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">PHP Login using Google Account</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <?php
   if($login_button == '')
   {
    echo '<div class="panel-heading">Welcome User</div><div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION["user_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail" />';
    echo '<h3><b>Name :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].' '.$_SESSION['user_last_name'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><b>Email :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_email_address'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</h3></div>';
    //header('location: home.php');
    include('home.php');
   }
   else
   {
    echo '<div align="center">'.$login_button . '</div>';
   }
   ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>```
````